# WSO2: adding code to emm-utils (ZipFileReading.java)

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I've added code to ZipFileReading.java, but i can see that the only calls to it's methods are done in modules/apps/publisher/mobileupload.jag, adding my code this this file, doesn't effect the server...

1. What is *.jag file?
2. Where can I find the source that calls ZipFileReading methods (for example, when uploading an APK)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found my answers:

1. jag is a file created by jaggery (http://jaggeryjs.org/)
2. The problem here was that i tested the wrong compilation output zip file.